# Mathematica's GatherBy function using Pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I'm designing a function similar to the [GatherBy](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GatherBy.html) in Mathematica. I thought it could be easily done by dressing up `groupby` function in Pandas. This function will group the list by certain given characteristic function.

**Setup**

```
time1 = pd.date_range(start=datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 30), end=datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 5))
datedat = np.array([time1, 0.1 * numpy.arange(7), 0.2 * numpy.arange(7)]).T

print(datedat)
array([[Timestamp('2015-01-30 00:00:00', freq='D'), 0.0, 0.0],
   [Timestamp('2015-01-31 00:00:00', freq='D'), 0.1, 0.2],
   [Timestamp('2015-02-01 00:00:00', freq='D'), 0.2, 0.4],
   [Timestamp('2015-02-02 00:00:00', freq='D'), 0.3,
    0.6],
   [Timestamp('2015-02-03 00:00:00', freq='D'), 0.4, 0.8],
   [Timestamp('2015-02-04 00:00:00', freq='D'), 0.5, 1.0],
   [Timestamp('2015-02-05 00:00:00', freq='D'), 0.6,
    1.2]], dtype=object)
```

Suppose I want to group it by year and month —— you see there are data for January and February. So I design a characteristic function:

```
gatherf = lambda x: ((x[0].year)*1000+x[0].month)
```

For every time-data records, this `gatherf` would calculate a value for `groupby` to distinguish time.

**Objective**

my final object is to develop a function `gather_by`, by which

```
gather_by(datedat, gatherf)
```

Should generate this:

```
array([[[Timestamp('2015-01-30 00:00:00', freq='D'), 0.0, 0.0],
   [Timestamp('2015-01-31 00:00:00', freq='D'), 0.1, 0.2]],

   [[Timestamp('2015-02-01 00:00:00', freq='D'), 0.2, 0.4],
   [Timestamp('2015-02-02 00:00:00', freq='D'), 0.3,
    0.6],
   [Timestamp('2015-02-03 00:00:00', freq='D'), 0.4, 0.8],
   [Timestamp('2015-02-04 00:00:00', freq='D'), 0.5, 1.0],
   [Timestamp('2015-02-05 00:00:00', freq='D'), 0.6,
    1.2]]], dtype=object)
```

---

**My Effort**

In general cases, the `datedat` might have more column than 3. I couldn't group them one by one. So I tried:

```
datedatF2 =pandas.DataFrame({'dat':datedat,'gather_key':numpy.array(list(map(gatherf, datedat)))})
```

with

```
groupedall=datedatF2['dat'].groupby(datedatF2['gather_key'])
```

but this leads to `Data must be 1-dimensional` error. what should I do?

Comment: Your variable names need a little work... also, can you please concretely outline what your input is vs what your expected output is for said input?

Comment: The input is datedat, a date-dat records list and  a characteristic function gatherf. The output should be a grouped list, contains all information in original list. @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Comment: Can you guarantee the first column is _always_ the date?

Comment: No. The first column could be _anything_. I could write different gatherf for different cases.

Comment: Okay, good. Next, `gatherf` operates on the first column? Or could it operate on anything?

Comment: Also, how much flexibility do you have over `gatherf`?

Comment: `gatherf` could  operate on any column. For example, `gatherf2 = lambda x: ((x[1]>0.2)`  operates on the second column. `gatherf3 = lambda x: (sum(x))` operates on the whole line if the elements in datedat are all numbers.

Comment: I see. I was looking to see if there was room for optimisation, but it would seem the easiest way to do this would be to have `gatherf` tailored to work on arrays, and then use pandas only for grouping. Note that building the `key` would be the bottleneck. Also, the other answer seems to have missed the point of your question.

Comment: `gatherf` takes the ith record ` {xi,yi,zi,...}` in `datedat` as input and generate a value.

Comment: Cleaned up your question, hope that's fine.

Comment: @Harry - please check my edited answer, faster is another approach - creating `Series` for `groupby`.

Comment: @jezrael The point of this question was never performance. OP has to write a custom function to operate upon the arrays. Pandas here is just a convenience. Your solution is hyper specific to the problem of date times and cannot ever hope to generalise.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - `cannot ever hope to generalise` are you sure? you can create custom Series, so it is very nice genneralize. I strongly disagree with you.

Comment: @jezrael I mean that `s = dates.dt.year*1000 + dates.dt.month` is tailored for the purpose of working with datetimes. But, this "GatherBy" is expected to work on any number of columns (not just series), and any arbitrary function (not just dates and times). That's what I mean by "generalisation", which your code, while faster, does not do. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - yes, maybe then is necessary use another pandas vectorized function(s). I want to say I think is not good approach custom functions here, better is use pandas functions.

Comment: @jezrael Agreed, however in this case, I don't think it is possible based on the nature of the problem :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inputs -

`datedat`

```
array([[Timestamp('2015-01-30 00:00:00', freq='D'), 0.0, 0.0],
       [Timestamp('2015-01-31 00:00:00', freq='D'), 0.1, 0.2],
       [Timestamp('2015-02-01 00:00:00', freq='D'), 0.2, 0.4],
       [Timestamp('2015-02-02 00:00:00', freq='D'), 0.3, 0.6],
       [Timestamp('2015-02-03 00:00:00', freq='D'), 0.4, 0.8],
       [Timestamp('2015-02-04 00:00:00', freq='D'), 0.5, 1.0],
       [Timestamp('2015-02-05 00:00:00', freq='D'), 0.6, 1.2]], dtype=object)
```

`gatherf`

```
lambda x: ((x[0].year) * 1000 + x [0].month)
```

---

One *very reliable* method of grouping building on your current approach, would be passing a custom list/key to `groupby` (the grouping predicate need not belong to the dataframe!) -

```
key = list(map(gatherf, datedat))

r = []
for _, g in pd.DataFrame(datedat).groupby(key):
    r.append(g.values.tolist())
```

Alternatively, as a list comprehension -

```
r = [g.values.tolist() for _, g in pd.DataFrame(datedat).groupby(key)]
```

```
np.array(r)

[[[Timestamp('2015-01-30 00:00:00', freq='D'), 0.0, 0.0],
  [Timestamp('2015-01-31 00:00:00', freq='D'), 0.1, 0.2]],
 [[Timestamp('2015-02-01 00:00:00', freq='D'), 0.2, 0.4],
  [Timestamp('2015-02-02 00:00:00', freq='D'), 0.3, 0.6],
  [Timestamp('2015-02-03 00:00:00', freq='D'), 0.4, 0.8],
  [Timestamp('2015-02-04 00:00:00', freq='D'), 0.5, 1.0],
  [Timestamp('2015-02-05 00:00:00', freq='D'), 0.6, 1.2]]]
```

This should also work for any number of columns, provided `gatherf` is appropriately written to match.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `groupby` by mapped function `gatherf`:

```
datedatF2 = pd.DataFrame(datedat)

gatherf = lambda x: x[0].year*1000 + x[0].month

out = [x.values.tolist() for i, x in datedatF2.groupby(list(map(gatherf, datedat)))]
print (out)

[[[Timestamp('2015-01-30 00:00:00', freq='D'), 0.0, 0.0], 
  [Timestamp('2015-01-31 00:00:00', freq='D'), 0.1, 0.2]], 

[[Timestamp('2015-02-01 00:00:00', freq='D'), 0.2, 0.4], 
  [Timestamp('2015-02-02 00:00:00', freq='D'), 0.3, 0.6], 
  [Timestamp('2015-02-03 00:00:00', freq='D'), 0.4, 0.8], 
  [Timestamp('2015-02-04 00:00:00', freq='D'), 0.5, 1.0],
  [Timestamp('2015-02-05 00:00:00', freq='D'), 0.6, 1.2]]]
```

First solution with `Series`:

```
datedatF2 = pd.DataFrame(datedat)
dates = pd.to_datetime(datedatF2.iloc[:, 0])

s = dates.dt.year*1000 + dates.dt.month
print (s)
0    2015001
1    2015001
2    2015002
3    2015002
4    2015002
5    2015002
6    2015002
Name: dat0, dtype: int64

out = [x.values.tolist() for i, x in datedatF2.groupby(s)]
```

EDIT:

Second approach si faster:

```
N = 100000
df = pd.DataFrame({1:pd.date_range('2015-01-01', periods=N, freq='15H'),
                   2:np.random.randint(100, size=N),
                   3:np.random.randint(100, size=N)})
datedat = df.values


In [75]: %%timeit
    ...: datedatF2 = pd.DataFrame(datedat)
    ...: dates = pd.to_datetime(datedatF2.iloc[:, 0])
    ...: s = dates.dt.year*1000 + dates.dt.month
    ...: out = [x.values.tolist() for i, x in datedatF2.groupby(s)]
    ...: 
1 loop, best of 3: 249 ms per loop

In [76]: %%timeit
    ...: datedatF2 = pd.DataFrame(datedat)
    ...: gatherf = lambda x: x[0].year*1000 + x[0].month
    ...: out = [x.values.tolist() for i, x in datedatF2.groupby(list(map(gatherf, datedat)))]
    ...: 
1 loop, best of 3: 359 ms per loop
```

**Caveat**:

Performance depend on the data - size of `DataFrame` and number of values groups. But generally second solution is faster as first.

Comment: You've radically modified your answer, it's now almost exactly like mine. Any thoughts?

Comment: Second solution is faster because it uses better method to calculated the key (years and months)? In general cases the first column might not necessary be datetime.

Comment: Inm y opinion in pandas are not used `map`, because slow. I think itt is faster because vectorized.